# Get called number of an incoming call in android

Tags: android

My question may look a bit strange.
I want to know if, in android, it is possible to know which number has been called when you receive an incoming call (I'm not speaking about caller id).

For example: let's assume  that my phone number is 555-12345, my operator will route to my phone every number starting with 555-12345.
This means that you can call me by dialing 555-12345, but also by dialing 555-12345-37967 or 555-12345-34 etc.
Is there a way to know which number the caller has dialed?

If it is not possible to do this using Android API, would be possible to achieve my goal at lower level? Maybe using a customized firmware?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @insomniac - That's not what's important.

Comment: i mean if you want it for a specific user or do you want to get the dialed number from any user?

Comment: @insomniac I would like to get the number from any user. I could think to many different reasons to do this, for example to have different phone numbers without relying on many phones or crappy dual-sim handsets.

Comment: sadly that's not possible ...

Comment: Even doing it at OS level, maybe with a custom "ROM"?

Comment: It may be possible in a dual-sim type of environment, but for most call-forwarding services, the forwarding happens *before* it gets to your phone. If that's the case, you'll only ever get the *final* number, not the one the caller called.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this and not found any answer, the sample app (sipDemo) do not handle incoming call too. Fortunately I found the answer:

`mSipManager.getSessionFor(intent).getPeerProfile().getUserName()`

Good luck ;)